# Alguien sabe como randomizar el orden de las preguntas

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda para poder randomizar las preguntas, que cada que le de start de un orden diferente. Ahorita el código lo único que hace es leer las preguntas del otro archivo y con la función verifica si son correctas o no.

```
from preguntasPI import quiz

def check_resp(question, ans, aciertos):
    if quiz[question]['answer'].lower() == ans.lower():
        print(f"Correcto! \nAciertos: {aciertos + 1}")
        return True
    else:
        print(f"Incorrecto")
        return False
    

nombre = input("Cual es tu nombre?: ")
escuela = input("Cual es tu escuela?: ")

aciertos = 0
intentos = 0
calificacion = 0


for question in quiz:
    intentos = 3
    while intentos > 0: 
        print(quiz[question]['question'])
        answer = input("Enter Answer: ")
        check = check_resp(question, answer, aciertos)
        if check:
            aciertos += 1
            calificacion += 1
        break
print("Tu calficiacion total es: ", calificacion)
```

Edit: código de quiz. Esta parte del código solo son las preguntas que aparecerán en el quiz con sus respuestas correspondientes. Lo que me gustaría lograr es que el orden de estás preguntas cambie cada vez que se ejecuta el programa.

```
quiz = {
    1 : {
        "question" : "En que fecha se celebra la independencia de México?",
        "answer" : "16 de Septiembre"
    },
    2 : {
        "question" : "Que se celebra el 2 de Noviembre?",
        "answer" : "Día de Muertos"
    },
    3 : {
        "question" : "Cuantos estados tiene México?",
        "answer" : "32"
    },
    4 : {
        "question" : "Quién escribió la Odisea?",
        "answer" : "Homero"
    },
    5 : {
        "question" : "Cual es el río más largo del mundo?",
        "answer" : "Amazonas"
    },
    6 : {
        "question" : "De qué país se originaron los juegos olímpicos?",
        "answer" : "Grecia"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin saber que es exactamente `quiz` ni que operaciones define ...

Comment: Puedes generar números aleatorios con [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) y usarlos para ordenar las preguntas.

Comment: Serias tan amable de colocar el código de quiz para saber su estructura o que tipo de dato tiene.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Este código produce la lista `desorden`, que contiene las llaves (desordenadas) de `quiz`.

```
orden = list(quiz.keys())
desorden = []
while orden:
    i = random.randint(0, len(orden) - 1)
    desorden.append(orden[i])
    del orden[i]
```

El método es simple. La lista `orden` contiene las llaves de `quiz`. En cada iteración del `while` sacamos un valor al azar de esa lista y lo agregamos a la lista de salida (`desorden`). Con esto la lista `orden` se va acortando y la lista `desorden` va creciendo.

#### Demo

```
import random

quiz = {
    1 : {
        "question" : "En que fecha se celebra la independencia de México?",
        "answer" : "16 de Septiembre"
    },
    2 : {
        "question" : "Que se celebra el 2 de Noviembre?",
        "answer" : "Día de Muertos"
    },
    3 : {
        "question" : "Cuantos estados tiene México?",
        "answer" : "32"
    },
    4 : {
        "question" : "Quién escribió la Odisea?",
        "answer" : "Homero"
    },
    5 : {
        "question" : "Cual es el río más largo del mundo?",
        "answer" : "Amazonas"
    },
    6 : {
        "question" : "De qué país se originaron los juegos olímpicos?",
        "answer" : "Grecia"
    }
}

orden = list(quiz.keys())
desorden = []
while orden:
    i = random.randint(0, len(orden) - 1)
    desorden.append(orden[i])
    del orden[i]
    
for key in desorden:
    print(quiz[key])
```

produce:

```
{'question': 'De qué país se originaron los juegos olímpicos?', 'answer': 'Grecia'}
{'question': 'Cual es el río más largo del mundo?', 'answer': 'Amazonas'}
{'question': 'En que fecha se celebra la independencia de México?', 'answer': '16 de Septiembre'}
{'question': 'Quién escribió la Odisea?', 'answer': 'Homero'}
{'question': 'Que se celebra el 2 de Noviembre?', 'answer': 'Día de Muertos'}
{'question': 'Cuantos estados tiene México?', 'answer': '32'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```